# Module "LinkedIn integration" for Drupal

Tags: drupal, linkedin-api

Established in Drupal module "linkedin integration".

I have an API Key and Secret key on //www.linkedin.com,

There are two problems:

1) The module is configured, but you receive this error:

"401 : No LinkedIn account is associated with this user"

2) Posting of Content not working

If I edit a page and try to post it to linkedin it doesn't work. If I turn on debug I get the following:
Linkedin debug : LinkedIn.com answered "< : <

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I've never used this module :( , but maybe this link helps you. https://drupal.org/node/1065038. I'm sorry for the short information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem one is that you have not yet linked your user with your linked in user.

To do this you should login as a normal user (password username from drupal).

Then when you go to your user edit screen you should see a tab linkedin if you click on it it will offer you the possibility to link your account. Make sure you are not in admin overlay mode it might not redirect you to linked in then.

[image: Linkedin tab]

After that save and you should be able to login

The posting problem can be more things.

I noticed that it takes pretty long for your post to appear in linked in so it might be that.

You did not show the rights you gave your application but make sure that in linked in you  at least selected "rw_nus" 
Linkedin documents show that right as doing:

> Retrieve and post updates to LinkedIn as you

Im talking about the settings here:

[image: Oauth user agreement]

The message debug gave back does not seem to mean anything (is a bug in the module i believe). I tested it myself and i got the same message and my post did appear a few minutes after that in linkedin